# Not sure if enqueuing js scripts properly

Tags: functions, jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

When I put this code right above the closing of my body tag it works, but when I try to enqueue it, it breaks. I'm thinking maybe jQuery isn't getting called? The snippet is from  [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#comment-197181)

FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scroll_port' );

function scroll_port() {
    wp_register_script( 'scrolling', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('scrolling');
}
```

SCROLL.JS

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
});`
```

Comment: the simplest way is to look at the page's source in a browser and search for your script to be sure it's there and the url is correct. but I'd guess your issue is related to [WordPress' jQuery being in noConflict](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Answer (score 1):

On your SCROLL.JS file, add the line before anything else,

```
(function($){
```

And after everything else

```
})(jQuery);
```

This block will load you code after jQuery is loaded, and will avoid the errors.